# Computing net distance (Euclidean distance) in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have asked about and receive great help for computing Euclidean distance in R before. Now, I need to compute the Euclidean distance from the first point relative to all the other points within the track data.
Here is how my data looks like:

```
dput(head(t1))
structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), T = 0:5, X = c(668L, 
668L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 668L), Y = c(259L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 
259L, 259L), V = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A", "T", 
"X", "Y", "V"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And SimonO101 was so great in giving me a code that will compute the Euclidean distance from the starting position to the final position for each track:

```
## Split the data
dfs <- split(t1,t1$A)

## Find hypotenuse between first and last rows for each A
lapply( dfs , function(x){
  j <- nrow(x)
  str <- x[1,c("X","Y")]
  end <- x[j,c("X","Y")]
  dist <- sqrt( sum( (end - str)^2 ) )
  return( dist )
} )
```

How do I edit the code, so that it will not just have the Euclidean distance from start to end, but from every X,Y position?
Thanks again!

EDIT:
And also: How to visualize the results as a matrix. Thank you

Comment: Once you have a matrix with two columns (one for x and one for y coordinates), `dist(mymatrix)` should be all you need.

Comment: Karen, just use `lapply( dfs , function(x) dist( x[,3:4] , diag = TRUE ) )` you don't really need `diag = TRUE`, but it helps to see that `dist` calculates zero distance between a point and itself!

Comment: @SimonO101 thanks once again! How do I put the data that it produces into a matrix on the workspace? Results just popped out into the console. Thanks!

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc assign it to a variable!! i.e. `results <- lapply(....` Note, that it will give you a list of matrices, one matrix for each unique track. To access a specific one use the `[[` operator, i.e. if you assign the output to a variable called results, then `results[[1]]` will give you the distance matrix for the first track.

Comment: @SimonO101 what I mean is that it will be in the workspace as data (I am using R Studio). Thanks!

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by that? Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @SimonO101 whenever I assign it as a variable, it appears in my workspace under the "Values" category. I want to view the results as data, or in a form of a matrix. Thanks

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc you have a list of matrices. One for each unique track. To view a matrix use results[[1]], or results[[2]]. I can't understand what else you mean!! Sorry! You either assign the results to a variable or you just run the line I gave you and the results show up in the console output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28822/discussion-between-karen-grace-bondoc-and-simono101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `dist` function in the `stats` package. You can apply it to your data easily enough:

```
lapply( dfs , function(x) dist( x[,c("X","Y")] , diag = TRUE )[1:nrow(x)] )
```

The idea being that we operate on each dataframe, applying the `dist` function to the `"X"` and `"Y"` columns of each data frame. The subsetting at the end ( `[1:nrow(x)]` )is used to return only the distances between the first point and all the other points. Remove this subsetting if you want a full distance matrix for each track.

Comment: @Karen if you just want distance between first point and all others using this subsetting will be better. If you want the whole matrix for all the points use what I posted in the comments above.

Comment: by first point here, do you mean the first point of each track? Because I have to compute for each track independently. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean first point of each track. That is why we are using `lapply` again. We previosuly split your data into a list of dataframes, one dataframe for each track. We now independently use `dist` on the dataframe for each track (remember we split your data using the `split` function in your previous question). What you get back is a list of the distances, *for each track* between the first point and all other points.

Comment: when I checked the data using the script that you gave, it sorts of recycle the results in the last data of each track. Thanks!

Comment: @KarenGraceBondoc no problem. You should try to work out how it works. Try running it on `lapply( dfs[[1]] ....` to see what happens. You should only get the results for the first track back... `lapply` is a convenient way to type: `take this list of stuff (in your case a list of dataframes) and apply some function to each item in the list`.

Comment: Yes I have used lapply. I tried with [1:nrow(x)-1] and it gives the right values. But I am lacking one row as it puts the result of the 1st dist value on the 1st row of each track.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean without an example of the actual output and then the desired output, but you can try to use parentheses, i.e. `[1:(nrow(x)-1)]`

Comment: Yes, I have used that already. But then my data set now lacks 20 values (which is one value missing per track) as the first result of each track is placed on the first row.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution :

```
f <- function(x) {
j <- nrow(x)
end <- as.numeric(x[j,c("X","Y")])
x <- x[-j,c("X", "Y")]
dist <- colSums((t(x)-end)^2)
dist
}
lapply(dfs, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to calculate Euclidean distance directly in the function?

E.g. with this function am trying to calculate distance up to 8 m between observations, but I want to add a condition of only calculating distances between observations from the same group? My observations are trees with x,y position coordinates from different plots (11 plots, 2000 trees).

```
`search_dfixed <- function(id, x, y, dist) {
.class <- if (class(id) == "factor") {
"character"
 } else {
 class(id)
 }

 m <- as.matrix (dist(data.frame(x, y)))

 rownames(m) <- id; colnames(m) <- id

 z <- as.data.frame(m) %>%
 tibble::as_tibble() %>%
 dplyr::mutate(id = id) %>%
 tidyr::gather(competitor, .dist, -id) %>%
 dplyr::filter(
  .dist != 0,
  .dist <= dist
  ) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(id, .dist) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
  id = 'class<-'(id, .class),
  competitor = 'class<-'(competitor, .class)
  )

  return(z)
  }`
```