# Computing Euclidean distances between subsequent positions

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have large data frames consisting of pairs of X and Y coordinates, and wish to calculate the Euclidean distances between consecutive coordinates (minimal size is around 2000 pairs of coordinates).

Thus, I want to calculate the distance from row 1 to 2, row 2 to 3, row 3 to 4, etc.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192483/computing-net-distance-euclidean-distance-in-r) nicely shows how to calculate the Euclidean distance between the first and last point for track data, but my data are closer to:

```
dff <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), T = 0:5, X = c(668L, 670L, 672L, 674L, 676L, 678L), Y = c(259L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 259L, 260L), V = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A", "T", "X", "Y", "V"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It seems like there should be a way to create a loop to do this, but I'm uncertain about how to subscript this.  Using `dist()` is computationally demanding for datasets of this size and in any case I am also unsure of how to extract matrix elements that are one-off from the diagonal.

Comment: Have you looked at the `sp` package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
sqrt(diff(dff$X)^2 + diff(dff$Y)^2)
```

should work. The key here is the `diff` function, which gives differences between consecutive items in a vector

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, just for fun:

```
sqrt(apply(apply(dff[,c("X","Y")], 2, diff)^2, 1, sum))
```