# Calculate Euclidian distance over rows of dataframe

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe such as this:

```
d<-data.frame(x=c(400.4,400.2,400.1,394.3,396.5),
           y=c(330.2,330.2,330.1,289.9,288.8))
```

I can calculate the Euclidian distance for the first two rows like this:

```
dist(d[1:2,]) #0.2
```

If I wish to do this for every successive row, e.g. distance between rows 1&2, 2&3, 3&4 etc. I have written a for loop, but this is incredibly slow with thousands of rows.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: With [`proxy`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=proxy): `proxy::dist(d[-nrow(d), ], d[-1L, ], method="Euclidean", pairwise=TRUE)`

Comment: You can [extract the diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231961/extract-diagonals-from-a-distance-matrix-in-r) from the result of `dist(d)`: `out <- as.matrix(dist(d));
out[row(out) == col(out) + 1]`

Comment: `sqrt(diff(d$x)^2 + diff(d$y)^2)`

Comment: Perhaps this: [Computing Euclidean distances between subsequent positions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340318/computing-euclidean-distances-between-subsequent-positions-in-r)